# mice returns Error in nnet.default: too many weights

Tags: r, r-mice

I used mice package which have an error：

> Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  : too many (1734) weights;

I try to set

```
imp<-mice(w,MaxNWts = 2000,seed=1234)
```

but show another error：

> Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  : 
>         formal argument "MaxNWts" matched by multiple actual arguments

what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem;

`imp<-mice(w,seed=1234,nnet.MaxNWts = 2000)`